# Designing a PUT and PATCH API Endpoint Having Common Domain Object

Tags: json, scala, api, patch

I have the following Domain object that my API endpoint expects as a JSON in its body:

```
final case class MyDomanObj(
  id: Int,
  name: String,
  field1: String,
  field2: Double,
  field3: String,
  field4: String
)
```

For the PUT endpoint, it is clear that I can have this as a entire JSON object and parse it to this case class, but the problem comes with the PATCH endpoint, where I might expect a few fields and the JSON parsing might fail. I can workaround this by making all the fields in the MyDomainObj to be optional, but that would be terribly wrong.

Any ideas on how to elegantly design a PATCH endpoint? I'm more interested to know how I can parse the JSON body to get the subset of the fields that comes in the request.

Comment: Why having all fields as optional in another case class would be wrong?

Comment: I don't know why, but it sounds to be a bit awkward to set all the fields optional just to satfisfy an API endpoint.

Comment: Not really, API case classes model what API does. If PATCH should allow modifying whatever you want then Option or similar might be ok. Unless you are forcing them all to align with the domain (which should be modeled for other things than API, so having them all be implemented by the same classes would feel wring) it's all right.

Comment: So you mean to say that I should have all the fields in the case class to be optional so that I can have the PATCH endpoint also implemented with proper JSON parsing. Correct?

Comment: You should have one case class to model each endpoint input. And other case classes to model your business model. You want to decorrelate your API models from your internal business model.

Comment: Modelling one case class per API endpoint is not something that would work for PATCH request as with 6 fields I can come up with 6*6 case classes to represent each combination of requests that might come in. It is not a wide idea in this case.

Comment: Perhaps not, but even something like `case class APIObject[F[_]](field: F[Value])` and then making it `APIObject[Id]` for put and `APIObject[Option]` for patch and then having a separate object for domain works pretty well. Otherwise you are at risk of modifying your inner domain representation every time you change something with your FE. And lifecycle of endpoints and API is pretty decoupled from lifecycle of what happens internally, so reusing the objects just because can become a problem. You can also reuse objects between endpoints - just separate them from domain objects.

Comment: I could not follow you. Could you post a solution with your idea?

Comment: I meant one case class per endpoint. One endpoint should only accept one kind of input. For PATCH, all fields optional.

Comment: I'd say: write your API case classes and sealed traits to make it as easy to generate the codecs as possible. If JSON has nullable field, make it `Option`. If 2 endpoints take/return different JSONs, make different case classes. If JSONs share some element's structure, make this element a separate case class and use it in other 2 case classes. The less custom codecs you need to write, the better. Just DO NOT reuse API case classes in your domain logic. Translate data in API calls to and from domain objects to not paint yourself into the corner.

Comment: I tried to follow your advice of using a type constructor, but I ran into some simple errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74693229/scala-cats-import-for-id-monad-results-in-compilation-failure