# Scala cats import for Id Monad Results in Compilation Failure

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I do not understand how such a simple thing would be complicated? I'm trying to use the Id Monad from the typelevel cats library and for this purpose, I have added the following as my sbt dependency:

```
val scalaCATS = "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "2.9.0"
val scalaCATSKernel = "org.typelevel" %% "cats-kernel" % "2.9.0"
val scalaCATSEffect = "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "3.4.2"
```

I then have defined the following in my object like this:

```
import cats._

import java.net.URL
import java.time.ZonedDateTime

case class LocationAPIObject[F[_]](
  countryCode: F[String]
)
object Locations {

  val api = LocationAPIObject[Id] //
  ......
  ......
}

[error] 40 |  val api = LocationAPIObject[Id]
[error]    |                              ^^
[error]    |                              Not found: type Id
```

Any ideas as to what else I'm missing here?

[image]

Comment: Check your dependencies again, e.g. with an IDE, this works if you pass some argument into `.apply[Id]`: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/619Si8BhRsWonVd8tcOjTQ

Comment: I don't know why. May be I will delete the .idea and re import the project.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Do you know how I could wrote a JSON codec for such a data type? I'm currently using the play json library for formatting back and fort from JSON to Case class and vice-versa.

Comment: Was it a compilation error in IntelliJ or in sbt? It's a good idea to make clean from time to time. `sbt clean compile`

Comment: Unable to replicate, may I suggest using another compiler such as `scala-cli` or plain `sbt`?

Comment: Also, for your JSON codec problem, I recommend using Circe for your case class encoding, it has a really convenient api for automatic and semi-automatic codec derivation: https://circe.github.io/circe/codec.html

Comment: Play JSON let you generate codecs like this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated - I strongly suggest that no matter what you pick: Play JSON, Circe, Jsoniter, Jackson - keep a separate case classes for JSONs so that you won't have to write codecs yourself, but have them generated. It: 1) removes the need to figure out how to write a codec, 2) makes obvious what the case class is encoded to/decoded from.